# How to build apk from source code of android web browser?

Tags: android, open-source

Got source code android default web browser from below link:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser

But how to build APK of the same.

Tried with executing make Browser in terminal. 
But it says make: *** No rule to make target `Browser'.  Stop.
Am i missing any basic thing??